# Python - dissect a 'domain' to all his suffixes

Tags: python

What is **a very optimal** way, given a domain of the form (`a.b.c.d` etc.) where the number of `strings` between `'.' is > 1`, to get a list of his suffixes, ordered by the longest suffix, descending.

For example given `www.hello.com` I'd like the following output:

```
['www.hello.com', 'hello.com', 'com']
```

Comment: This is not all of _his_ suffixes , what about `www.hello` ?

Comment: This is a prefix. I don't want them. only suffixes between dots. given `a.b.c` a suffix must end with `c`

Comment: what does it mean to be **optimal**?

Comment: I left it open to interpretation on purpose because I can't define the optimal complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `split` the string on `'.'` with a `maxsplit` argument, the last element will be the suffix:

```
>>> domain = 'www.hello.com'
>>> domain.split('.', 0)
['www.hello.com']
>>> domain.split('.', 1)
['www', 'hello.com']
>>> domain.split('.', 2)
['www', 'hello', 'com']
```

So, you just need to take the last element of each split:

```
>>> [domain.split('.', i)[-1] for i in range(domain.count('.')+1)]
['www.hello.com', 'hello.com', 'com']
```

Is this "**very optimal**"? I have no idea. It's pretty fast:

```
In [259]: %timeit [domain.split('.', i)[-1] for i in range(domain.count('.')+1
2.43 µs ± 121 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

---

Comparing [Arman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51578040/908494), I'd expect a small constant-factor difference, because of the cost of that `join`, but rather than guess, let's test it:

```
In [261]: s = domain
In [262]: %timeit ['.'.join(s.split('.')[i:]) for i in range(len(s.split('.')))]
3.79 µs ± 119 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So, yeah, it's slower by about 55% (more than I expected, actually), but still, we're talking a microsecond here.

---

Can we come up with something faster? Maybe, but it'll be more verbose. We're calling `split` repeatedly on the whole string. What if we just `split` it once and `join`ed multiple times? I suspect `join` is a bit faster because it doesn't involve a search, until you get to big enough strings where allocation is a faster, but again, let's not guess, let's test:

```
In [264]: %timeit parts=domain.split('.'); ['.'.join(parts[i:]) for i in range(len(pats))]
2.41 µs ± 86.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Well, that saved 20 nanoseconds.

---

Either of those solutions technically has quadratic complexity.

Could we do it in linear time?

First, what if we just got the positions of the `.`s and sliced? That's still actually quadratic time, because each slice is still a linear-time operation, even if it's a much faster one than a `split` or `join`.

But then *anything* we do in Python is guaranteed to be quadratic here. We have to create N new strings whose average length is a factor of N, and that means `N*N` characters being allocated and copied.

If we could get a new string object that references the same string buffer as `domain[pos:]`… Well, you can't do that in Python, but you could theoretically do it in C. But first, let's see if it looks worth doing:

```
pos = 0
dots = []
while True:
    dots.append(pos)
    pos = domain.find('.', pos)
    if pos == -1: break
    pos += 1
[domain[pos:] for pos in dots]
```

This is a bit trickier to time, but it takes 7.02µs. All that extra work, and all those extra `if`s, waste a lot more time than we save. Maybe if you had a huge number of components, it would be worth it, but for three? I doubt it.

Writing this logic in C might well be faster than using `split` or `join`, even without sharing the string buffer, and then tricking Python into constructing string objects around that shared buffer might save a bit more… but unless that 2 microseconds is really a bottleneck in your code, do you really want to write a C extension here? (And you'd have to be *really* careful—string objects expect to own their storage, and you don't want the splits deleting a buffer they don't own…)

---

If you really need speed here, given that your string is pure ASCII, you'd probably save more time by using a `bytes`. (And then you can even `memoryview` it to avoid copying the slices, but at the cost of not being able to do things like `print` them without an extra step…) Of course bytes are less convenient to work with, and if you could have IDNA domains in human-readable Unicode instead of IDNA punycode it won't work at all…

Comment: I see you are very enthusiastic about this. The full scale problem is much more interesting If you want to open a chat and discuss it.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
s = 'www.hello.com'
splits = s.split('.')
['.'.join(splits[i:]) for i in range(len(splits))]
# ['www.hello.com', 'hello.com', 'com']
```

I'm not sure this *very optimal* but first thing come in my head.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution ARMAN! Thank you. But I think abarnerts' is more optimal

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be much slower. Yes, it does N joins and N splits instead of just N splits, but joins are pretty fast. But rather than guessing, I timed it… it's about 55% slower on my laptop with this example input. So I guess it's slower than I expected. But still, does that 1µs really make a difference in your code?

Comment: Its 1µs times N which can be huge. But ARMAN solution is actually is good as yours if you make `s.split('.')` in a different line. Just like `In [264]`

Comment: @EranMoshe How huge is your N? If you're just processing a file of a few hundred thousand of these, it's 0.2 seconds. If your code really needs to do this a billion times, there's probably a higher-level optimization you can make, like not building and iterating over these lists in the first place. But, without knowing more about what you're doing this for, it's hard to say. And my experience is that when people ask for "very optimal" code on Stack Overflow without explaining anything, they usually don't even have a performance problem in the first place.

Comment: You're mostly correct. It's good enough. Specially after splitting before iterating.